# reactjs component props propagation in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I try to write typescript code to propagate component properties in subcomponents by writing the following react code in the render method :

```
<MyComponent {...this.props}> </MyComponent>
```

The typescript compiler seems not to accept this syntax. Any workaround?

Comment: @XavierMéhaut  Try it with `typescript@next`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the workaround is to use a React.CreateElement instead :
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html
while waiting for typescript taking account this syntax

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about TypeScript + React combination, however, the following code does not return an error:

```
/// <reference path="./typings/react/react.d.ts" />
import React = require('react');

interface HelloWorldProps {
    name: string;
}

var HelloMessage = React.createClass<HelloWorldProps, any>({
    render: function() {
        return <div {...this.props.name}>Hello</div>;
    }
});
```

and it transpiles to

```
/// <reference path="./typings/react/react.d.ts" />
var React = require('react');
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return React.createElement("div", React.__spread({}, this.props.name), "Hello");
    }
});
```

when I run it with the following command (tsc 1.7.5):

```
tsc --module commonjs --target es5 --jsx react main.tsx
```

This means that spread operator is supported. I don't know why it does not work for you. Maybe [this article](http://staxmanade.com/2015/08/playing-with-typescript-and-jsx/) will be of some help.